# DateTime.DayOfWeek return wrong day

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, dayofweek

I created a **LINQ** query to get the `DayOfWeek` for a date in my database. The query (I tried to figure it out, so this is just the query I use in **LinqPad**) looks like this:

```
(from e in Containers
 where e.IsEmpty == false &&
     e.DepotArrivalRetunDateTime.GetValueOrDefault().Date > DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7) &&
     e.DepotArrivalRetunDateTime.GetValueOrDefault().Date <= DateTime.Today
 select
 new
 {
     WeekDay = e.CustomerDepartureReturnDateTime.GetValueOrDefault().DayOfWeek,
     Bla = e.DepotArrivalRetunDateTime.GetValueOrDefault().Date
 }).ToList()
```

The value I get in return is the following table:

```
Tuesday    7/6/2016 12:00:00 AM 

Tuesday    7/6/2016 12:00:00 AM 

Tuesday    7/5/2016 12:00:00 AM 

Monday    7/4/2016 12:00:00 AM 

Thursday    7/7/2016 12:00:00 AM
```

As you can see, the returned `DayOfWeek` for `7/5/2016` is `Tuesday` as well as the `DayOfWeek` for `7/6/2016` which should be `Wednesday`. I can't figure out where the problem might be. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is getting day-of-week from CustomerDepartureReturnDateTime but it's getting date from DepotArrivalRetunDateTime.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've searched for hours on my error - sometimes it is that simple...

Comment: You need a vacation.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be related to the format of DATE in these different tables or databases, since June 7th was Tuesday as well.

I mean, one dataset is configured to MM/DD and the other is DD/MM.

Comment: Datetime fields in every RDBMS I've ever used (several) are not stored with formatting.